# SEO with Rails - How can I change headings in a partial based on the action (eg. index vs. show)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have a store with Products. I created a `_product.html.erb` partial that has a summary of the product, and I use it for both the index and show pages.

The issue is, I want the product name to be an `<h1>` heading in the product show page, but an `<h2>` on the index page. I want to do this because I have many product on the index page, and I'm not sure if it makes sense to have a large number of `<h1>`s on the same page. For the show page, I only have that one product, so definitely want to use the `<h1>`.

The way I did this was with an if/else clause in the partial as below, but it's a bit messy. Is there a better way to do this?

**product/_product.html.erb**

```
<div class="product_partial">
  <% if params[:action] == "show" %>
    <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
  <% else %>
    <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
  <% end %>          
  <h3><%= product.description %></h3>
</div>
```

**product/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="product_show">
  <%= @product %>
  <%= @product.other_info %>    
</div>
```

**product/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="product_index">
  <%= @products %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this

product/_product.html.erb

```
<div class="product_partial">
    <<%= heading_tag %>><%= product.name %></<%= heading_tag %>>         
    <h3><%= product.description %></h3>
</div>
```

product/show.html.erb

```
<div class="product_show">
    <%= render @product, :heading_tag => 'h1' %>
    <%= @product.other_info %>    
</div>
```

product/index.html.erb

```
<div class="product_index">
   <%= render @products, :heading_tag => 'h2' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Babur. Does this work in rails 3.2? I get `undefined local variable or method `heading_tag'`